# Find the Path of a Audio.Media item

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I am trying to do a custom media player. Currently I am retrieving all the songs from the phone by:

```
audioCursor = this.managedQuery(Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, Audio.Media.TITLE+" ASC");
        startManagingCursor(audioCursor);

        String[] columnsToMap = new String[] { 
                Audio.Media.TITLE, 
                Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME
        };
        int[] mapTo = new int[] {
                R.id.song_tf_1,
                R.id.song_tf_2,
                R.id.song_tf_path
        };

        ListAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, 
                R.layout.song_list_song,
                audioCursor, 
                columnsToMap, 
                mapTo
        );

        setListAdapter( mAdapter );
```

the only problem is that I don't know hot to get the PATH of the song so I can add it to a

```
player.reset();
player.setDataSource(songPath);
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

How can i get the songpath for every song and save it in a field (R.id.song_tf_path) ... Or is there any alternative I can do this better? Preferably without having to manually scan all the folders for music, etc

Answer (score 2):

It just looks like you can replace `DISPLAY_NAME` with `DATA` and it should work out fine. Keep in mind though, it's an absolute path, and probably will be of considerable length.

Since you're using `setListAdapter()` I'm going to assume you're using list activity. In that case, add an `onListItemClick()` method in your class to perform an action when it receives a click. The method should give you an `id` so you know which item was clicked.

Something like this would work

```
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String[] projection = new String[] {Audio.Media._ID, Audio.Media.DATA};
    Cursor c = managedQuery(ContentUris.withAppendedId(Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id),
                                                    projection,
                                                    null,
                                                    null,
                                                    null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String p = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Audio.Media.DATA));

    //your code to load this path into your media player
    //and play it goes here

}
```

The song's path will be stored in p, and you can do whatever you'd like with it.